# Comparing properties of nodes and vehicles as penalty in CVRP problem with ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

I am still new to using ortools and seem to lack a basic understanding of creating constraints and penalties.

My problem statement:

All locations to which vehicles can travel have properties. For example, only vehicles with the same property can travel to certain places.

How can I now implement a soft constraint that a vehicle can only travel to a location if it has the correct value of a property? If the vehicle does drive to the location, it should receive a penalty accordingly.

Thank you in advance for your help with my problem.

I have already gone through the examples on the ortools website and tried to create two callbacks, one for the distance and one for mapping to a specific binary property. Unfortunately, with `routing.RegisterTransitCallback(iswoundmanager_callback)` in the callback function you don't have any vehicle information available, only from the origin and destination, which means you can't compare properties between location and vehicle.

```py
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index, vehicle_id):
        # Returns the distance between the two nodes.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        vehicle_iswm = data['vehicle_iswoundmanager'][vehicle_id]
        penalty = 0
        if vehicle_iswm != data['node_needwoundmanager'][to_node]:
            penalty = 10  # Woundmanager property mismatch penalty
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node] + penalty

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
```

Creating a dimension for a binary property didn't make sense to me either, since dimensions do add up values over distance, but I just want to do a comparison for each transit and either give a penalty or not, depending on whether the property between location and vehicle matches or not.